# JQuery delete LI element by ID

Tags: jquery

My fiddle link is

http://jsfiddle.net/tBYdu/18/

and I don't understand why when I push `button` it deletes all following `<li>` instead of deleting only the selected `<li>` by `ID`?

Comment: You were attaching all button not corresponding to that list. Modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBYdu/32/)

Comment: Unrelated issue: numeric IDs are allowed in HTML5, but not HTML4. IDs should start with a letter or `_` for maximum portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you apply the click handlers to all buttons..

`$('button')` will get applied to all buttons that are present in the html..

Try a single

```
$('ul').on('click','button', function(){
   $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/tBYdu/29/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are attaching every click function to *all* the buttons.
By using the selector `$('button')` you are selecting every button to attach your click handlers to.

Comment: So when you click one button, you're firing all of your delete handlers.

Answer (score 2):

You are repeadtly binding event with button that is why all button are deleted. You need to `bind the event once`. `$('button').click will bind the event to all button types`. You do not need to repeat it as you did.

Try something like this for all buttons,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/B76JR/1/)**

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: Should be `$(this).parent().remove();`

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you attach `click` events to all buttons on the page. Each new event binding appends new handler to the existing one. So finally the browser reads your code like if it is written in the following way:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#16').remove();
    $('#17').remove();
    $('#19').remove();
    $('#23').remove();
    $('#25').remove();
});​
```

... meaning, when you click any `<button>` element on the page all elements with IDs `16`, `17`, `19`, `23` and `25` will be removed.

An alternative way is to use the following once in `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tBYdu/34/

Answer (score 0):

Any time you click one of the buttons, all of the scripts fire, since your selector is simply the element 'button'.  Try assigning each button an ID and using the ID to fire off the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

when you bind events it will find all the current elements the DOM has, so some of your buttons will have multiply click events.

if you want to remove the buttons parent then:

```
$('li button').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

or use `.closest("li")` instead of `.parent()`

Answer (score 0):

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/tBYdu/30/

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Revise your selector and the handler function like below,

```
$('#4 button').click (function () { 
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Where `#4` is the ID of the `UL`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tBYdu/33/